# Get the type of AnyObject dynamically in Swift

Tags: swift

I have passed a parameter to a function of type AnyObject because anything can be passed to it. Is there a way to get the type of Object passed, dynamically?

Comment: I would say, that no one answer in this topic wasn't help me. My issue was i can't obtain type information during debug, to get know how to handle the Any object, to see the actual content, because i didn't know the type of Any object i didn't know to which type i need to cast it to see the content.
And the best solution for me is cast the Any object to NSObject and look it's className property for example :
        ((json["glossary"] as NSDictionary)["title"] as NSObject).className
it shows me "__NSDictionaryM", and for example on :

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Typically this is what generics are for. There is seldom good reason for having an `AnyObject` in code that doesn't interact with ObjC. If you're then performing different actions based on the type, then you probably actually meant to use overloading.

That said, there are several ways to get access to the type. Typically you want to run different code depending on the type, so you can use a `switch` for that:

```
let x:AnyObject = "asdf"
switch x {
case is String: println("I'm a string")
default: println("I'm not a string")
}
```

or

```
let x:AnyObject = "asdf"
switch x {
case let xString as String: println("I'm a string: \(xString)")
default: println("I'm not a string")
}
```

Or you can use an if:

```
if let string = x as? String {
  println("I'm a string: \(string)")
}
```

See "Type Casting for Any and AnyObject" in the Swift Programming Language for more discussion.

But again, unless you're working with ObjC code, there is seldom reason to use `Any` or `AnyObject`. Generics and overloads are the tools designed to solve those problems in Swift.

Answer (score 31):

It's not clear what you mean by "the type" in your question. For any value of any type in Swift, you can get its dynamic runtime type like this:

```
theVariable.dynamicType
```

What you can do with it is another question.

Swift 3 version with [@jojodmo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2767207/jojodmo)'s hint:

```
type(of: theVariable)
```

Comment: This should be the anwser for this question.

Comment: In Swift 3, It's been changed to `type(of: theVariable)`

Answer (score 0):

First import Foundation

and if you wan't the type of test1 do that:

```
var test1 = "test"

println(_stdlib_getTypeName(test1))
```

You will get "TtSS"  TtSS mean String.

if you would try with a Int it would be TtSi (i for int)

Comment: Keep in mind that these type names are private and subject to change at any time. The leading underscore in the function name is an indicator from Apple that this is an internal function that is not intended to be called from outside the stdlib.

Answer (score 0):

```
func testType(value:AnyObject!){

    if let v = value as? NSString{

        println("NSString")

    }else if let v = value as? NSNumber{

        println("NSNumber")

    }else if let v = value as? Double{

        println("Double")

    }else if let v = value as? Int{
        println("Int")
    }
}
```

Comment: Please add some explanation.