# Can i have 2 types on parameter in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, function, parameters, arguments

so i've created function and it does something, but i want it to do something else if the parameter type is different, for example:

```
func (parameter: unknownType){
    if(typeof parameter == Int){
        //do this
    }else if(typeof parameter == String){
        //do that
    }
}
```

i've done this in javascript or other programming languages, but i don't know how to do this in swift

i've created function which takes 1 argument UITextField and centers it using constraints

now i want to center my button, but since button is not UITextField type it does not work, so is there a way i can tell function to do the same on UIButton??

Comment: OK, generally I suggest Victor's answer. In your case, both classes (UITextField and UIButton) use parents functionality for what you need to do. So simply use the right parent class as a parameter!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Overload:

```
class Example
{
    func method(a : String) -> NSString {
    return a;
    }
    func method(a : UInt) -> NSString {
    return "{\(a)}"
    }
}

Example().method("Foo") // "Foo"
Example().method(123) // "{123}"
```

Comment: this is probably the best answer ... and should be accepted. The only disadvantage is, that it is not applicable for globally defined functions.

Answer (score 2):

The equivalent of the Javascript code would be:

```
func doSomething(parameter: Any?) {
    if let intValue = parameter as? Int {
       // do something with the int
    } else if let stringValue = parameter as? String {
      // do something with the string
    }
}
```

But be warned, this approach makes you loose the type safety which is one of most useful feature of Swift.

A better approach would be to declare a protocol that is implemented by all types that you want to allow to be passed to `doSomething`:

```
protocol MyProtocol {
    func doSomething()
}

extension Int: MyProtocol {
    func doSomething() {
        print("I am an int")
    }
}

extension String: MyProtocol {
    func doSomething() {
        print("I am a string")
    }
}

func doSomething(parameter: MyProtocol) {
    parameter.doSomething()
}


doSomething(1) // will print "I am an int"
doSomething("a") // will print "I am a string"
doSomething(14.0) // compiler error as Double does not conform to MyProtocol
```

Answer (score 0):

It can
Sample code:

> ```
> func temFunc(obj:AnyObject){
>     if let intValue = obj as? Int{
>         print(intValue)
>     }else if let str = obj as? String{
>         print(str)
>     }
> }
> ```

Comment: This will not work neither for `Int` nor `String` as those types can't be matched to `AnyObject`, so calling `temFunc(1)` will result in a compiler error.

Comment: No, i try and successful with temFunc(1) and temFunc("hello")

Comment: This means you have imported `Foundation`, and the params get converted to NSNumber, respectively NSString

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of `Any` and downcasting:

```
func foo(bar: Any){
    switch(bar) {
    case let a as String:
        /* do something with String instance 'a' */
        print("The bar is a String, bar = " + a)
    case let a as Int:
        /* do something with Int instance 'a' */
        print("The bar is an Int, bar = \(a)")
    case _ : print("The bar is neither an Int nor a String, bar = \(bar)")
    }
}

/* Example */   
var myString = "Hello"
var myInt = 1
var myDouble = 1.5

foo(myString) // The bar is a String, bar = Hello
foo(myInt)    // The bar is an Int, bar = 1
foo(myDouble) // The bar is neither an Int nor a String, bar = 1.5
```

Answer (score -1):

Check this solution:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/25528882/256738

You can pass an object `AnyObject` and check the class in order to know what kind of object it is.

**UPDATE**

Good point @Vojtech Vrbka

Here an example:

```
let x : AnyObject = "abc"
switch x {
  case is String: println("I'm a string")
  case is Array: println("I'm an Array")
  // Other cases
  default: println("Unknown")
}
```